# What is a proper way to add web server to my TCP server application

Tags: c#, .net

I'm at the beginning of my journey with C# and now I have a question and I need your advice on it.

I have a TCP server application on the C# net core, now I want to add a web server to add a REST endpoint to have the ability to take data from the server, like connected clients, etc... My SDK is `Microsoft.NET.Sdk`, framework: `net6.0`.

So what is the best way to add this REST endpoint and implement a web server? I guess that I need something like this in the MVC C# application, please clarify is my thought are correct.

Comment: If you already have a TCP server just have the clients call it directly.   I don't see the need for an API Server.

Comment: _"implement a web server"_ -  do you mean web _service?_

Comment: Why do you want to do this? TCP is a low level protocol, to use it you always need to define your protocol on top of it. There are many *standardized* protocols to chose from depending on your needs. Http, RabbitMq, MQTT and many others. But in the vast majority of cases you should use an existing implementation, especially if you are new to programming. So my advice would be to throw away your tcp server and use the existing webserver in asp.Net.

Comment: If you're trying to expose your data via a web-server: just use asp.net core - you'll have a working web-server and REST endpoints in literally a few lines of code; you *really* shouldn't be writing your own TCP server and then implement http yourself - that's a *huuuuge* thing, that already exists for you

Comment: here we go: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/min-web-api?view=aspnetcore-7.0 (you can also use the controller approach if you prefer; that example is one above on the left navbar)

Comment: @MarcGravell Idea is not to write a TCP server and implement HTTP on my own, the idea is to add HTTP to the existing TCP server that will work on the same application but on a different port, 80 in my case. So my TCP server will accept and work with connections on a custom port and on the 80 port, I want to have an HTTP server. Is it a bad practice?

Comment: @Mavis ah, it sounded like you had the TCP part, and now you wanted to implement http on top of that (since HTTP1/2 are TCP-based); in this scenario, honestly: I'd just switch everything to Kestrel (the asp.net core server); Kestrel *also functions as a raw TCP server*, and frankly there's a good chance that it is a better TCP server than yours (meaning: more reliable and efficient); here's an example that implements http and "RESP" (the redis protocol) via TCP: https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/blob/main/toys/KestrelRedisServer/Program.cs (using older aspnet APIs)

Comment: I would start a new project using the webserver template and add the existing TCPServer to it. I think this is way easier than adding the webserver afterwards.

Comment: @MarcGravell Ok, thank you. I will check your option, maybe this will be a better solution. I just wanted to keep these parts separate like the TCP server is just a server, web panel for it - this is another service.